# Can't start my-weather-indicator under 16.04

Tags: 16.04, my-weather-indicator

I just installed the Beta 2 of Ubuntu 16.04.

After that I installed my-weather-indicator with this commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install my-weather-indicator
```

I wanted to start the program with:

```
/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/bin/my-weather-indicator
```

But I get this error log:

```
/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/bin/my-weather-indicator:27: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk
/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/bin/my-weather-indicator:28: PyGIWarning: Notify was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Notify', '0.7') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Notify
<gettext.GNUTranslations object at 0x7f2d5602b7b8>
/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/share/my-weather-indicator/myweatherindicator.py:31: PyGIWarning: AppIndicator3 was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as appindicator
/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/share/my-weather-indicator/geocodeapi.py:30: PyGIWarning: GeocodeGlib was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('GeocodeGlib', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import GeocodeGlib
/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/share/my-weather-indicator/whereami.py:27: PyGIWarning: WebKit was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('WebKit', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import WebKit
#####################################################
System: Linux
Machine: x86_64
Node: TP420
Release: 4.4.0-15-generic
Version: #31-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 18 19:08:31 UTC 2016
Platform: Linux-4.4.0-15-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial
#####################################################

My-Weather-Indicator version: 0.7.9-0extras15.10.0
#####################################################

HTTPConnectionPool(host='openweathermap.org', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f47b2481b38>, 'Connection to openweathermap.org timed out. (connect timeout=1)'))
Waiting for internet
```

How can I fix this issue?

// Edit:
This issue was actually fixed by the developer.
See here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/my-weather-indicator/+bug/1569161

Comment: I am confident the developer will update their PPA soon.

Comment: Could you answer your own question and accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was actually fixed by the developer. See here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/my-weather-indicator/+bug/1569161